# Find the fixed points of the difference equation $ \ a_n=\frac{2}{7} a_{n-1}-1 \ $

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Find the fixed points of the difference equation  $ \ a_n=\frac{2}{7} a_{n-1}-1 \ $ . Classify the fixed points whether stable, unstable or Neutral.

**Answer:**

Let $ \ x \ $ be the fixed point.

Then,

$ x=\frac{2}{7} x-1 \\ \Rightarrow 7x=2x-7 \\ \Rightarrow 5x=-7 \\ \Rightarrow x =-\frac{7}{5} $

**But how to decide whether $ \ x =-\frac{7}{5} $ is stable or unstable.**

Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $a_n=b_n-\frac75$. The recurrence is

$$b_n-\frac75=\frac27\left(b_{n-1}-\frac75\right)-1=\frac27b_{n-1}-\frac75,$$ or

$$b_n=\frac27b_{n-1}.$$

You should be able to conclude.

Comment: since $ \frac{2}{7} \ <1 $ , the fixed point is stable. Am i right ?

Comment: So, is it stable?

Comment: @yourmath: choose an initial $b$ and compute a few values... The answer is obvious.

Comment: If we let $ b_0=1 \ $ , then $ \ b_n=(\frac{2}{7})^n \to 0 \ \ as \ \ n \to \ \infty \ $ . Thus, $ \ a_n=b_n-\frac{7}{5} \to -\frac{7}{5} \ \ as \ \ n \to \infty \ \Rightarrow the \ \ fixed \ \ point \ \ is \ \ unstable. \ $  Am I right ?

Comment: @yourmath: wrong. But how do you conclude instability from this ?

Comment: so what would be the result ?

Comment: @yourmath: mh, if you say instable and I say wrong, there a little other options. But you didn't answer my question.

Comment: i am lost here about how to conclude the finishing. So guide me here

Comment: You wrote $\implies$ the fixed point is unstable. Why ?